# WPF Pop up View

Tags: wpf

I have a View (View B) that contains a grid and an OK and Cancel button

The view is simply used so that the user can select a row and press OK or they can cancel out of the screen

I want this view to pop up when the user presses a button on a different view (View A) and to be able to capture the button press in the View A when the user presses OK or Cancel.

I'm not sure of the best technique to use to do this in WPF

Can someone point me to an example?

Comment: got your point.. you want to return the selected record from the View B to View A.  But you can not hook the View B Ok_Click event in View A but yes you can return the object from View B to View A thats possible..

Answer (score 0):

Typically your Views would have underlying ViewModels and the ViewModels would use the message bus to send the messages to each other.

Check out Tony Sneed's [Climb Onboard on the MVVM Message Bus](http://blog.tonysneed.com/2011/03/03/climb-onboard-on-the-mvvm-message-bus/) blog post which tackles this in much more detail and than use his [Simple MVVM Toolkit](http://simplemvvmtoolkit.codeplex.com/) MVVM framework so you don't have to implement the message bus yourself...